# How to find replacement toilet seat (American Standard)

Tags: toilet, bathroom-fixtures

How do I determine what seat will fit this toilet and are colored seats available?

Inside the tank are these numbers:
1459
388
M59
Aug26

Thank you.

[image: view 2]

[image: view 1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Toilet seats are available in a variety of colors and materials, plastic, wood, padded. There are dozens if not hundreds of options.

Your toilet *appears?* to have an elongated bowl, as opposed to a standard bowl, so you need to make sure you get an [elongated seat](https://www.lowes.com/pl/Elongated--Toilet-seats-Toilets-toilet-seats-Bathroom/4294737208?refinement=2795156766).

Most seats are universal fit, except for some custom toilets, so you should be able to buy an elongated seat, or a standard, in a color you like. Just two bolts at the back of the seat go though two corresponding holes in the bowl.

You can get soft close hinges to keep it from slamming down.

[Example seat](https://www.lowes.com/pd/Bemis-Lift-Off-Plastic-Elongated-Slow-Close-Toilet-Seat/50082538).

[Vintage Bermuda Coral Toilet American Standard Compton 4043 Pink Retro One Flush](https://www.pinterest.com/pin/173881235591791596/)

OR

[Mid century "Standard" toilet, Pink](http://www.plumbing-geek.com/pinktoilet.html)

*That's right, i have nothing better to do then spend time looking at 50 year old pink toilets on the intertubes.* ;)-

Comment: I was hoping to identify the American Standard replacement in the same color as the original. I thought that would give me the correct color. Choosing a color on the web is hit and miss. To get the exact color for my fixture, I thought I would need the model and part number.

Comment: Don't limit yourself to the exact color. (a) colors change over the years, so it may not be available anyway, (b) by being flexible on color, you open up **many** more possibilities for padded, slow-close hinges, etc.

Comment: Contact American Standard directly @ https://www.americanstandard-us.com/parts-support/contact-us  That is an old toilet, an exact match may not be possible.

Comment: @Yehuda_NYC  "*I was hoping to identify the American Standard replacement*"  That is not how the question was worded. **The question was**, "*How do I determine what seat will fit this toilet and are colored seats available?*"  If you want to change the question then use the **edit button to add the correct wording** BUT shopping questions are off topic here and it is unlikely someone is going to want do your research for you.

Comment: The question as originally asked was more general. Perhaps I should leave it and post a new question.

Comment: This is a very old toilet. I doubt American standard still makes that color/seat. Try finding a used one on ebay or craigslist or  a used housing materials stores. There where a lot of them made so it is possible to find  a used one.  I do not think we can answer your question as precisely as you would like. You should sell me your toilet, it matches my tub perfectly, same era.

Comment: @Yehuda_NYC Your general question as asked here is acceptable.  Your "help me pick an exact match seat for my toilet" is a **shopping question** and those are off-topic here.  Anyway the answer can only be "call the manufacturer", we won't have any secret sauce that'll make that less of a chore (is it a chore, even?)

Answer (score 1):

Most toilets in the USA use one of two sizes, and have for many years even as the water usage and tank size have changed. Measure the existing seat at its widest and distance from mounting holes to front and you should find an easy match in any hardware store.

Once you know the type, you can find what colors, finishes, materials, hinges etc. are available.